# Metric space with non-metric topology?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Given a metric space $X$, we usually define a topology on $X$ said to be *induced* by the metric, which behaves very nicely. But my question is: what happens if we define a topology on $X$ *other* than the induced metric topology? Does it make sense to do so? Is it ever useful? Or is there really only one meaningful way to define a topology on $X$?

**EDIT:** I think I should clarify: of course it is possible to define a topology on $X$ and then completely ignore the metric, thinking of $X$ only as a topological space. But what I'm curious about is whether there's any situation in which it is useful to keep *both* the metric *and* the topology, despite them not being "compatible" with each other, and use them to prove something or solve a problem.

Comment: Sure it's useful. $X$ is just a set, you can put any topology on it you want.

Comment: @MPW But don't you get conflicting notions of convergence, openness etc. if you do?

Comment: I guess something like that is the weak-$*$ topology, which is not necessarily compatible with the norm (which in turn means it isn't compatible with our given metric), but it's still useful.

Comment: @Andreas: Quite so. That's what it *means* for the topology to be different. Using different topologies on the same set often gives very interesting spaces, frequently useful for counterexamples etc.